# Is オージー understood by non-Australian Japanese speakers?

Tags: words, slang, loanwords

Is the word "オージー" (in the meaning of "Aussie", not as in "old girl" or other meanings) understood by non-Australian Japanese speakers?

Also, in English, non-Australians have a [tendency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aussie#Usage_notes) to use "Aussie" as noun to mean the country, which Australians don't do. Do Japanese use "オージー" to mean the country?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, answer is no. Ordinary Japanese who never lived in Australia or NZ, don't understand the word.

In Japan,most familiar word is オージー・ビーフ. Many understand origin of the beef is Australia.

In other means.

OG. Office Girl. But it is not used so many today.
OG Sohken. Osaka Gas company's IT and think tank subsidiary. Abbreviation of Osaka Gas Sohgo Kenkyuusyo.